# MySQL and 2-columns Primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm beginning with MySQL, trying to set up a 2-columns primary key, I'm using phpmyadmin.

I managed to somehow mark two columns as a primary key ([this is what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qWr0.jpg), the primary columns are underligned) but they seem to act as two separate primary key, I can't add rows with the same ID and different region, or reversibly the same region and different ID.

What should i fix ? thanks !

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/how-to-set-up-multiple-fields-as-primary-key-in-mysql

Comment: Can you add the content of the image as a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (run from the mysql command line, or look in phpmyadmin for the table structure) here?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` you will most likely see the following:

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
region VARCHAR,
....
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY somename (id,region)
```

So what has been created for you is a unique key. A unique key can be used as primary key, but you will have to get rid of your other primary key `id`.

This can be done by:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Since I do not know all your specs, test the result and see if all the desired behavior is still in place.